# Regular expression look-back matches correctly but doesn't replace in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

My objective is to remove all text in a 〔〕 and a single trailing space when the 〔〕 is proceeded by a tab and some other character.

I am using the following regex in Notepad++:

```
(?<=\t.)(〔.*?〕 )
```

The target string is as follows (there are tabs before the ●):

```
    ●〔nope〕 howdy!
    ●〔〕 howdy!
    ●(nope) howdy!
    〔nope〕 howdy!
```

When I use an on-line regex tester, the above first and second lines are matched (not the third or forth), which is what I want.
However, in notepad++ when I change the search mode to regex and use the search/replace feature with the above regex it correctly matches the string but nothing is replaced (the replace string is blank). That is to say, when I press the find button "〔nope〕 " is matched correctly, but when I press replace thereafter the matched string remains.

Is my regular expression syntax wrong, or is there something wrong with Notepad++? The version I am using is 7.5.9.

Comment: I can reproduce on 7.5.4. The substrings are matched, but "Replace" doesn't replace them, only "Replace All" replaces them, for some reason.

Comment: This is a known issue related to the lookbehind as the first pattern. Replace with `(\t.)(〔.*?〕 )` and it will work. You may reference the first group using `$1` or `\1` to put it back where it was.

Comment: With Npp 7.5.9 32 bit, it works when you click on "Replace all" but not single "Replace" ;(